# Creating a dictionary out of pandas dataframe, where the value is the index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
A
a       
b
c
d
```

I am trying to create a python dictionary which would look like this:

```
df_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
```

What I've tried:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = {x : y for x in df['A'] for y in df['index']}
```

But the `df` is 75k long and its taking a while now, not even sure if this produces the result I need. Is there a neat, fast way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict` with `zip` and `range`:

```
d = dict(zip(df['A'], range(len(df))))
print (d)
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
#creating example dataframe with 75 000 rows
import uuid
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(75000) ] } )  

#your bit
{ i:v for i,v in  df.reset_index().values }
```

It runs in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert series to list and use enumerate:

```
lst = { x: i for i, x in enumerate(df['A'].tolist()) }
```